# How to make water condensate in a specific spot in a closed container?

Tags: water, condensation

I plan on making a large closed terrarium with a dry area and a wet area. How do I make sure that the evaporating water from the wet area does not condense into the dry area? I have found little to no info regarding this subject.

Comment: You'll have to devise a method to condense it within the wet area. probably by disconnecting the two areas.

Comment: I am not even sure if this is a question fit for PSE and not world-building SE

Comment: Can these two areas have different temperatures? Furthermore, if you write try area and wet area you are probably solely referring to the floor and not to the humidity of the air. Is this correct?

Comment: @Semoi Referring to the floor mostly but a little to the humidity, too. The two areas can have different temperatures.

Comment: @Lelouch You just reformatted my question. If I wanted to disconnect the two areas, I would simply build two separate ones. I deem it fit to PSE because the question is about water condensation and how to manipulate where it condenses.

Answer (score 1):

The first physical law I learned as a kid was the awesomely named "Law of the Cold Wall": condensation tends to happen on the coldest wall of a container. Strictly speaking it is not true (which is why the law is not well known): condensation happens on all cold enough surfaces, but it will be most intensive on the coldest ones and that can drain air moisture in a container in one place.

So I would suggest having cold piping close to the water section, condensing out moisture and letting it drip back in the water. The dry area meanwhile needs to be kept warmer than the wet area. Getting this to work *well* depends on engineering, not physics.